# Moving the contents of one vector to another

Tags: c++, vector, move

So I have a vector:

```
vector<Enemy*> enemies;
```

This vector hold enemies, which are created dynamically  throughout the game.

```
if(rand() % 1000 > 998)
{
Enemy * enemy = new Enemy(num_of_enemies);
        enemies.push_back(enemy);
}
```

The problem with this being is that the vector is ever growing even if the enemy has been deleted, which is slowing down my game.

Essentially I want to move the contents of the vector to a new one, but only the elements that actually hold an enemy.

I read that there was something called `std::move` but I'm not really sure how to implement it properly, or if it will successfully move the elements that contain enemies, and not just the whole vector.

Any help with code implementation of structuring would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems that in your design `enemies` vector stores pointers to already deleted enemies.

Comment: If you’re adding and removing lots of elements, consider using a `std::deque` or `std::list` instead. Furthermore, store `Enemy` objects, not `Enemy*` objects. Don’t use manual dynamic storage.

Comment: Using `vector<Enemy>` or `vector<shared_ptr<Enemy>>` would solve a lot of problems

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Not sure what you mean by this comment: it’s literally just paraphrasing the question.

Comment: The approach you're trying to do won't help. You have to remove the enemies from the vector before deleting them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I mean that it stores dangling pointers...

Comment: When the enemy is to be deleted I call the class destructor, and than I delete (or atleast try to) the section of the vector where the enemy was being held. I don't think I'm going this correctly though.


    `enemies[i]->~Enemy();
    delete enemies[i];`

Comment: 1. remove 2. delete

Comment: @Nick Indeed, that’s incorrect. Worse, it’s undefined behaviour. You need to read up on what `delete` actually does. But really, if you didn’t use pointers here (and an appropriate data structure; see above) then you wouldn’t have this problem in the first place.

Comment: I am more worried about your game algorithm and you will run out of memory. Would it be playable with that many enemies? Will it be better to generate only those within the viewing distance rather than the entire game world?

Comment: @seccpur I could be wrong, but if he's throwing all enemies into the same vector (and all enemies are the same type) i'd say this is probably just a console app.

Comment: Well It's just a simple 2D game. The enemies basically only exist when they are on screen, if they are hit by the player, of move off the screen they are to be deleted and removed from the vector. This is what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Also I tried making my vector a list, but now my code is filled with errors as apparently the list doesn't understand my iterator that is being used to loop through the vector.

Comment: how do you know if a enemy has been hit do you store positions? or the enemy class 'has' the position ?

Comment: Well if you've got your heart set on using a vector you could just say something like `delete enemies[whicheverElementYouWantToDelete]` and then`enemies.erase(enemies.begin()+whicheverElementYouWantToDelete)` or you could store a vector of smart pointers and just erase the smart pointer.

Comment: @SamerTufail The class hold the position of that enemy, and it's adjusted with a simple physics simulator. I also loop through the vector to check if any collision has occurred.

Comment: @George The second piece of script you added, would I add this immediately after I call the piece of delete code?

Comment: @Nick Yes, the idea is just delete whatever the pointer points to and then immediately remove the 'dangling' pointer from the list.

Comment: My suggestion will work but I would go with @Konrad Rudolph s answer if you can.

Comment: @Nick, if that is the case - I would avoid a vector, simply because you are going through all the values just to check for collisions. You can just have an unordered_map<position, Enemy*> - just see if your hit is at map[position] and then remove that value from map and call destructor on that Enemy :).

Comment: @SamerTufail Cool idea, but it won't help unless both the enemies and the bullets are points (ie don't have size).

Comment: @Андрей Беньковский dont have enough code to make that judgement and so the idea :) oh well.

Comment: @Андрей Беньковский one of the answers below suggests using a map with a similar idea though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a complete workflow of how to handle spawning and despawning enemies. Note that there are no pointers at all involved.

1. Spawning an enemy:

   ```
   if (if random_float_between_0_and_1() < 0.002)
       enemies.push_back(Enemy{arguments});
   ```
2. Despawning enemies; according to your comment below, should look something like this:

   ```
   auto last_iter = std::remove_if(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), is_dead);
   enemies.erase(last_iter, enemies.end());
   ```

   Here, `is_dead` is a function that takes an `Enemy const&` and determines whether it collided with a player or the screen bounds:

   ```
   bool is_dead(Enemy const& enemy) {
       return outside_screen_area(enemy) or near_player(enemy);
   }
   ```

   The functions `outside_screen_area` and `near_player` should be straightforward for you to implement.

   To understand how the code above works, consult the documentations of [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).

Another thing: implement the function `random_float_between_0_and_1` in terms of the standard library random library that ships with C++11. Don’t use `std::rand` or modulo operations on integer random numbers, they work badly (i.e. they’re not truly uniformly distributed and will give skewed results).

Comment: I'm just a little confused.

So is the code you supplied 2 functions?

The first being randomly spawning an enemy and the second being deleting it.

Does this mean that ` vector<Enemy*> enemies;` will need to be alter too? and what exactly am i passing into the despawn function?

Comment: @Nick Well where do you spawn and despawn your enemies? My functions are just placeholder for that code. The relevant part is the code *inside* my functions (to avoid confusion I’ll remove the functions from my answer!). Regarding the container, yes, you’ll have to change that to a `std::vector<Enemy> enemies;`.

Comment: I think this is all a little out of my league in terms of implementation.

I'm only a beginner and this is all a little overwhelming for me.

I understand the first function you added, in that it's basically a means of spawning enemies (an altered vector version or what I asked in my question), it's more the second one that confuses me. I think I get that it's like a range loop that loops through the vector, but what am I adding after "which" exactly?

Comment: @Nick My code is much simpler than yours: Just compare the number of indirections (pointers or otherwise) or lines of code. The problem is that you haven’t told us how you identify which enemy to kill/remove, so I had to guess.

Comment: @Nick It's hard to tell what you're asking, `which` would be the element to remove `enemies.erase(it);` will erase the object from the vector. This does mean you're vector will need to be a vector of enemy objects and not of enemy pointers. Note, the despawn code could be simplified to `enemies.erase(enemies.begin()+whicheverElementYouWantToD‌​elete)`

Comment: Well there are 2 ways my enemies can die, which is by either colliding with the player, or passing off the edge of the screen. I have loops that loop through the vector and check to see if the enemies position is the same (semi-same) as the player, and if it has left the screen. When either of these return true I:`1.  enemies[i]->~Enemy(); 2. delete enemies[i];` which to me is that it's 1. Calling the enemy destructor on the enemy in element "enemies[i]" and 2. deleting the element of the vector itself. Which I guess I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @George I added that piece of code, making what I believe to be the appropriate amendment 'enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + i);' but yet the size of my vector is ever increasing. Am I executing it wrong?

Comment: @Nick See updated answer. I’ve simplified it drastically and added a concrete implementation; you should be able to use this directly, once you’ve implemented the missing functions. It’s fairly hard (= impossible) to make this any simpler. If your vector is still increasing after that, it means that your enemies aren’t getting killed, i.e. there’s an error in your logic for comparing the enemy position to the player/screen coordinates.

Comment: @Nick it does seem odd that the size would still increase, if it still isn't working, I would put a break point in the destructor of your `Enemy` class. If the breakpoint is hit, it probably means more enemies are being added and if it's not then as suggested above, check your logic and maybe put a breakpoint on whatever condition is required to call 'killEnemy' just to try and find where your code is going wrong.

Comment: @George I think I got it working! 

`enemies[i]->~Enemy();`
 `delete enemies[i];`
 `enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + i);`

I used these 3 line and I think that it worked. Before when I said that it wasn't working I believe that I didn't have the desctuctor code in there. But not for some reason I'm getting a runtime "Assertion" error. Not really sure what the go it with it.

Comment: @Nick Cool! Only thing is, you shouldn't need the `enemies[i]->~Enemy();` and Konrad was trying to say that you could store a vector of `Enemy` literals, `vector<Enemy> enemies;` instead of `vector<Enemy*> enemies;`and then you wouldn't need `delete enemies[i]; `. It would make the code cleaner and faster, but if you want to just keep using pointers, your code is fine, only, I really would remove `enemies[i]->~Enemy();`.

Comment: @Nick The runtime assertion is because, as I have mentioned in a comment below your question, this code is invalid and causes undefined behaviour. You must not call the destructor manually, `delete` already does this for you. But I believe we’re going in circles here because you’re still using pointers against my recommendations.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yeah I get that pointers aren't the way to go, but my entire code is pretty heavily set on what I have create (that being using pointers) and I feel if I start changing my code now it's going to drop me down a rabbit hole of not being able to fix what I have started. Plus I'm working to a timeline, and If I start making those sort of adjustments I might not be able to make my code function in time (or at all).

Comment: @Nick It doesn't really matter, but for future reference you shouldn't use pointers for something like this, it will make the code slower, less readable(arguably) and less safe(depending on the circumstance). Also whenever an object is destroyed, the destructor will always be called(with some exception but that probably doesn't matter here), I know it's already been mentioned but calling it `~Enemy();` manually could cause all kinds of weird shit to happen.

Comment: I came back to my code this morning, and now an error appears saying that `vector subscript is out of range`, does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Never mind, it was an issue with my falling projectiles.
@George. You were the one that supplied the code that allowed me to implement what I needed, although I can't close with your answer as it was within a comment. So to close off the topic I might choose KonradRudolph, just because you said that the code he supplied was basically the same as what you were doing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph. Thanks for all the code that you supplied, if I had a little more knowledge of C++ under my belt I might have the skills to implement your code. Although I do understand what your code was doing, there would be a heap of changes I would have to the entire code for it to work properly, and I'm not really keep to do that at this stage. Thanks again, and thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with this being is that the vector is ever growing even if the enemy has been deleted ...
>
> Essentially I want to move the contents of the vector to a new one ...

It seems to me that a simpler approach would be to remove the pointers to deleted objects from the original vector instead of making a copy.

There is no difference between a pointer to a deleted object that no longer exists and a pointer to an existing object. Therefore you must keep track of the elements that must be removed from the vector. The simplest solution is to remove the element immediately after it has been deleted. This becomes much easier with smart pointers since removing the pointer also deletes the object automatically.

`std::move` won't help you with this problem.

You may want to consider not using manual dynamic allocation at all. You can instead store `Enemy` objects in the vector.

> When the enemy is to be deleted I call the class destructor, and than [sic] I delete

`delete` expression calls the destructor. Calling it yourself also will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Does the code I've provided allow you to give me an example of how to delete the pointers to the vector?
If I'm creating enemies dynamically, why do you believe that I shouldn't be using dynamic allocation at all?

Comment: “You may want to consider not using dynamic allocation at all.” — This is the understatement of the century: **Do not use dynamic allocation here**.

Comment: Well than what do I do? Suggestion are what I need right now.

Comment: @Nick have you taken a look at the API of `std::vector`? it has an `erase` member function. I didn't say that you shouldn't be using dynamic allocation. I said that you should consider not using dynamic allocation. Your example shows no need for dynamic allocation. You haven't rationalized the use of dynamic allocation in the body of the question either. Use of dynamic allocation and pointers is more complicated than storing objects directly, which I suspect is the reason why you have fallen into the trap of incorrectly destroying the objects. I extended my suggestion with how to proceed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph vectors use dynamic allocation. In fact dynamic allocation and recursive automatic allocation are the only way to go, when the number of objects is not to be limited at runtime

Comment: @M.M The salient point is to avoid *manual* dynamic allocation. I omitted the word “dynamic” by mistake, but my comment below the question mentions this point.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you shouldn't use a data structure like *std::vector* if you want to remove a single element in a random position.  The complexity of this operation is **linear** on the number of elements after the deleted element.
As I understand, you have a number of enemies moving around a 2D screen side by side with one (or many) player(s). If an enemy is hit by a player or goes out of the screen, it will be deleted. You just loop over the list of enemies to see these conditions fulfilled.
In this case, I recommend you to use *std::map* to manage your created enemy objects.
Suppose that your Enemy class has a function to check deletion conditions, e.g:

```
bool Enemy::willbeDeleted() /* if true then will be deleted */
```

then here is a class using *std::map* to manage your enemy objects:
EnemyManager.hpp

```
#include <map>
class EnemyManager {
public:
  /*
   * Get the Enemy Manager
   */
  static EnemyManager& Instance();

  /*!
   *  Delete the instance of EnemyManager
   */
  static void deleteInstance();

public:
  /* Create an enemy object */
  void createEnemy();

  /* Check all enemy objects and delete any fulfulling condition */
  void checkEnemy();

  virtual ~EnemyManager();

private:
  /* Make sure we can not call EnemyManager constructor directly */
  EnemyManager();
  EnemyManager(const EnemyManager& objManager);

  /* Instance of EnemyManager */
  static EnemyManager* enemyManager;

private:
  /* List of current enemy objects */
  std::map<int, A*> enemyList_;

  /* Identity of already-create object, it increases on creating a new object */
  int enemyIndex_;
};
```

EnemyManager.cpp

```
#include "EnemyManager.hpp"
#include <vector>

EnemyManager* EnemyManager::enemyManager = 0;

EnemyManager& EnemyManager::Instance()
{
  if (0 == enemyManager)
  {
    enemyManager = new EnemyManager();
  }

  return *enemyManager;
}
void EnemyManager::deleteInstance()
{
  if (0 != enemyManager) delete enemyManager;
}

EnemyManager::EnemyManager() : enemyList_(), enemyIndex_(0)
{}

EnemyManager::~EnemyManager() {
 /* Nothing todo */
}

void EnemyManager::createEnemy()
{
  enemyList_[enemyIndex_] = new Enemy();
  ++enemyIndex_;
}

void EnemyManager::checkEnemy()
{
  std::map<int, A*>::const_iterator itb = enemyList_.begin(),
                                ite = enemyList_.end(), it;
  // Vector containing id of enemy object to delete
  std::vector<int> enemyToDelete;
  for (it = itb; it != ite; ++it)
    if ((it->second)->willbeDeleted())
        enemyToDelete.push_back(it->first);

  // Delete enemies and remove them from map
  for (std::size_t idx = 0; idx < enemyToDelete.size(); ++idx)
  {
    delete enemyList_[enemyToDelete[idx]];
    enemyList_.erase(enemyToDelete[idx]);
  }
}
```

you can use this class as follow :
in main.cpp

```
EnemyManager& enemyManager = EnemyManager::Instance();

if(rand() % 1000 > 998)
{
/* Create new enemy */
enemyManager.createEnemy();
}
/* Check all enemies */
enemyManager.checkEnemy();
```

There are two important functions:  *createEnemy* controls the way to create a new Enemy object, *checkEnemy* verifies objects and deletes them if needed and the size of enemyList_ won't increase forever :)
I believe with this approach, deleting enemies won't slow down your program anymore.
One of a drawback of this approach is that the number of created objects can be limited by 2^(8*sizeof(enemyIndex_))

Comment: You correctly identify that deleting enemies will take linear time with a vector. Yet your `checkEnemy` function *also* has linear runtime, and in addition has a much larger overhead — I guarantee that it will be vastly slower than e.g. the method in my answer, regardless of the number of enemies.

Comment: The `checkEnemy` can be slower than your method but I believe not so greatly. My approach is built in the fact that Enemy object is allocated by new and deallocated with delete. Your method is more concise and it's rather good in case we store Enemy objects directly in container :)